# Keeping datetime in a range with respect to data using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

I have a data set

```
BDate,Snum,ArrTime,OID,TDate,TTime,VID
1/1/2018,72,05:59:01,7214,1/1/2018,12:06:20 AM ,7206
1/1/2018,72,06:04:33,7208,1/1/2018,12:36:31 AM,7205
1/1/2018,72,06:21:07,7216,1/1/2018,5:53:49 AM,7220
1/1/2018,80,06:29:01,8026,1/1/2018,5:59:10 AM,7214
1/1/2018,72,06:30:54,7218,1/1/2018,6:04:55 AM,7208
1/1/2018,72,06:33:54,7221,1/1/2018,06:21:17 AM,7216
1/1/2018,80,06:35:26,8018,1/1/2018,06:31:04 AM,7218
1/1/2018,72,09:38:34,7211,1/1/2018,1:40:38 PM,7209
1/1/2018,72,13:39:45,7209,,,
```

The objective that I am looking at is to match columns on ArrTime to the nearest time in TTime which I have already achieve in my other post.

I am trying to improve the analysis by creating a time bound based on the ArrTime column. As you can see from the data set above, the 1st timing by ArrTime is 0:59:01 and the last ArrTime is 13:39:45. I would like to use this 2 timing(but last timing + 1min) as a time boundary to remove any time in TTime that doesnt fall within range.

As shown below is my code

```
mydataset = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python', index_col= False,header = 0, sep = ",")
mydataset['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['BDate'] + ' ' + mydataset['ArrTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
datesAM = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['TDate'] + ' ' + mydataset['TTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
datesPM = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['TDate'] + ' ' + mydataset['TTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
mydataset['Date2'] = datesAM.mask(mydataset['TTime'].str.endswith('AM',na=False), datesPM)
#print(mydataset)

df1 = mydataset[['Date1','Snum', 'OID']].sort_values('Date1').dropna(subset=['I'])
df1['OID'] = df1['OID'].astype(np.int64)

a = df1['Date1'].iloc[0]
a1 = a.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
print(a1)
b = df1['Date1'].iloc[-1]
b1 = b.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
print(b1)

df2 = mydataset[['Date2','VID']].sort_values('Date2').dropna(subset=['VID'])
df2['VID'] = df2['VID'].astype(np.int64)

df2[df2['Date2'].indexer_between_time(a1,b1)]

#df2['Date2'] = pd.date_range(start = a1, end = b1)
#print(df2)
```

I've tried using iloc to identify the 1st datetime and lastdate time then stripping it to timeformat. I've tried using pd.date_range and indexer_between_time but it all gave me error such as" 'Series' object has no attribute ' indexer_between_time'" and "Length of values does not match length of index"

My end goal is to remove the details(not the whole row but just TDate,TTime,VID) which do not fall within the range then do my matching of nearest time (Matching time has already been achieved)

```
BDate,Snum,ArrTime,OID,TDate,TTime,VID
1/1/2018,72,05:59:01,7214,,,
1/1/2018,72,06:04:33,7208,,,
1/1/2018,72,06:21:07,7216,,,
1/1/2018,80,06:29:01,8026,1/1/2018,5:59:10 AM,7214
1/1/2018,72,06:30:54,7218,1/1/2018,6:04:55 AM,7208
1/1/2018,72,06:33:54,7221,1/1/2018,06:21:17 AM,7216
1/1/2018,80,06:35:26,8018,1/1/2018,06:31:04 AM,7218
1/1/2018,72,09:38:34,7211,1/1/2018,1:40:38 PM,7209  
1/1/2018,72,13:39:45,7209,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by converting the datetime columns to unix timestamps so that it's easy for us to compare and filter out the datetime within the range.

This is how I would do it:

```
mydataset = pd.read_csv("data.csv", error_bad_lines=False, engine ='python', index_col= False,header = 0, sep = ",")
mydataset['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['BDate'] + ' ' + mydataset['ArrTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Function to clean dates because the format is not consistent. For example: We have *6:04:55 AM* and *06:21:17 AM* 
def cleanDate(x):
    if str(x) == 'nan':
        return np.nan
    else:
        temp = ''
        if int(x.split(':')[0]) < 10:
            temp += '0' + str(int(x.split(':')[0])) +':'
        else:
            temp += x.split(':')[0] + ':'
        temp += x.split(':',1)[1]
        return temp

mydataset['TTime'] = mydataset['TTime'].apply(lambda x: cleanDate(x))
mydataset['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['TDate'] + ' ' + mydataset['TTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', errors='ignore')
mydataset['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(mydataset['Date2'])

# Convert Datetime to unix timestamp and create a new column
mydataset['tsArrTime'] = mydataset['Date1'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()))
mydataset['tsTTime'] = mydataset['Date2'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()) if str(x) != 'NaT' else 0)

# Get min and max timestamp from tsArrTime column
minTime = mydataset['tsArrTime'].min() 
maxTime = mydataset['tsArrTime'].max() + 60  # End datetime + 1 min

# Check if tsTTime is within the range else replace with empty string (Change it to whatever you want)
mydataset.loc[(mydataset['tsTTime'] < minTime) | (mydataset['tsTTime'] > maxTime), 'TTime'] = ''
mydataset.loc[(mydataset['tsTTime'] < minTime) | (mydataset['tsTTime'] > maxTime), 'TDate'] = ''
mydataset.loc[(mydataset['tsTTime'] < minTime) | (mydataset['tsTTime'] > maxTime), 'VID'] = ''
mydataset['TTime'] = mydataset['TTime'].fillna('')
mydataset['TDate'] = mydataset['TDate'].fillna('')
mydataset['VID'] = mydataset['VID'].fillna('')

mydataset = mydataset.drop(columns=['Date1','Date2','tsArrTime','tsTTime'])
```

This is the output:

```
     BDate    Snum  ArrTime     OID     TDate       TTime           VID
0   1/1/2018    72  05:59:01    7214            
1   1/1/2018    72  06:04:33    7208            
2   1/1/2018    72  06:21:07    7216            
3   1/1/2018    80  06:29:01    8026    1/1/2018    05:59:10 AM     7214
4   1/1/2018    72  06:30:54    7218    1/1/2018    06:04:55 AM     7208
5   1/1/2018    72  06:33:54    7221    1/1/2018    06:21:17 AM     7216
6   1/1/2018    80  06:35:26    8018    1/1/2018    06:31:04 AM     7218
7   1/1/2018    72  09:38:34    7211    1/1/2018    01:40:38 PM     7209
8   1/1/2018    72  13:39:45    7209
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply! But could you share your output? 

Comment: Hi! I have an error of ' NaTType does not support timetuple' any advice? 

Comment: @ThanksForHelping Which line are you getting this error on?